# who is accessing /dev/video0

Tags: devices, camera, motion

I have a streaming video feed set up with the motion package.
something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGkHSU-UPLU

Works great. What I want to know, is who is connecting to my streaming media feed?
It's supposed to just be my boyfriend.

The light on my web camera is always on, even when he says he isn't viewing. I'm a little put off by this. Is there anyway to get more info about who (IP address) is viewing my stream?

Does the camera stay on even when no one is connected?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The camera light will be on while the camera is in use.  In this case, Motion is taking the feed and streaming it through the Motion web server.  This happens whether or not people are connected to your stream.

Assuming you're only using Motion I would edit the motion.conf in order to add authentication for the stream and also enable logging (to see who connects)

Read through the [configuration file](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/pub/Motion/ConfigFileOptions/motion-dist.conf), particularly the "Live Stream Server" section.

Read more about motion [here](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuide).